Why does "\" remain in bash quoted strings when escaping "!"?
I recently came across this surprising behavior involving " and ! in bash:
guy@guydell:~$ echo arbitrary echo
arbitrary echo
guy@guydell:~$ echo "!e" #unescaped history expansion
echo "echo arbitrary echo" #unescaped history expansion
echo arbitrary echo
guy@guydell:~$ echo "\!e" #escaped history expansion
\!e

Notice that in the second to last line, history expansion does not occur. This is because I used a \ to escape the !. However, the \ remains in the input to echo. This is not the case with e.g. ":
guy@guydell:~$ echo "\""
"

This behavior is documented:

If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.

I was curious as to what motivated this design decision. I would expect that, if a \ were to escape a character in a string of text, the \ would not be included in the string. Directions to an archive of an email list (which is where I assume this would have been discussed) or an excerpt from the discussion would both be appreciated.

I would speculate that ! is not considered special within strings because history expansion is a separate mechanism. In general, lone backslashes in double-quoted strings are not removed if the character after them is not special. It could also be overcorrection in the direction of ksh compatibility, since ksh has no history expansion at all.

You can set a different history expansion character, e.g. histchars='@^#'. The behaviour of \! remains the same, though.

Just in case you're not aware, you can get the behaviour you want with single quotes: echo '!e'.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions about interactive use.

You can also get the behavior you want by omitting the quotes: echo \!e
